# XKB Layout with Caps modifier, some combinations conflicting with other modifiers

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I created a custom keyboard layout in xkb format to simulate arrow keys and put it in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom`:

```
xkb_symbols {

    name[Group1]= "English (US) with Caps mod";
    key <ESC>  {    [   Escape, asciitilde, grave                       ]   };
    key <INS>  {    [   Insert, Insert, Caps_Lock                       ]   };
    key <TAB>  {    [   Tab, ISO_Left_Tab, Menu                         ]   };
    key <AC06> {    [   h, H, Left                                      ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [   j, J, Down                                      ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [   k, K, Up                                        ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [   l, L, Right                                     ]   };
};
```

After activating it with:
`setxkbmap -layout custom -option lv3:caps_switch` it works as expected, except for on annoyance:
Although I can use `Caps+{H,J,K,L}` to navigate via the simulated arrow keys, it is not possible to
combine it with other modifiers.
For example, the combinations `Super+Caps+{H,J,K,L}` or `Ctrl+Shift+Caps+{H,J,K,L}`) just don't work and I have to use the regular arrow keys for those.

Is there a way to get this working or is this a limitation of xkb?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able two get it working with the `lv3:caps_switch` option. Only after defining a separate two level modifier for caps, the simulated arrow keys worked together with other modifiers such as SUPER.

I have used the de layout as base, but it should work with others as well.
Here is my new `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom` file (`setxkbmap -layout custom -variant 5layer` to activate):

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys xkb_symbols "5layer" {

    include "de(basic)"
    include "ansi_hybrid(caps_layer)"
    include "ansi_hybrid(ralt_layers)"

};

partial modifier_keys xkb_symbols "caps_layer" {
    // caps layer key definitions

    replace key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Overlay1_Enable, Overlay1_Enable ],
        actions[Group1] = [ SetControls(controls=Overlay1),
                            SetControls(controls=Overlay1) ]
    };

    key <LatH> { Overlay1 = <LEFT> };
    key <LatJ> { Overlay1 = <DOWN> };
    key <LatK> { Overlay1 = <UP>   };
    key <LatL> { Overlay1 = <RGHT> };

};

partial modifier_keys xkb_symbols "ralt_layers" {
    // base, shift, ralt, shift+ralt layers key definitions

    key <CODE> {   [   base, shift, ralt_base, ralt_shift_symbol    ]   };

};
```